# How can I programmatically get a list of all object in a project with AX 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

How can I programmatically get a list of all object in a shared project?
I'm using Dynamics Ax 2009 SP1 RU7.

TIA,
Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

Use `infolog.projectRootNode()` or `SysTreeNode::getSharedProject()` to access the root node of shared projects.

Look [here](http://axdaily.blogspot.dk/2010/02/getting-project-treenode-iterator.html) for more information.

For at code example look [here](http://daynamicsaxaptatutorials.blogspot.dk/2011/06/code-to-get-all-object-of-project-node.html).